# Is it possible to have my Python script run when a certain file exists?

Tags: python

My script relies on user input. I want it to open up on its own and prompt the user to enter information after a certain file exists in a folder (another process is adding a file there). I don't want the user to worry about opening the script, I want it to automatically open and run, asking for user input just whenever that file comes into existence. How could I go about doing this? Just run another script checking when that happens?

Comment: If your platform is linux, you could use a cron task to check every n minutes if the file exists. What platform are you on?

Comment: sounds like you want a scheduler like a cron job on unix/mac

Comment: writing a python script that sleeps and then checks would be a more clumsy approach

Comment: You need 1) a program/script that checks for the existence of the new file and 2) A scheduler to run this script (unless you want it to run indefinitely)

Comment: Cron tasks and other scheduled items generally run in the background however, so you may not actually be able to interact with the process it kicks off.

Comment: another option aside from cron would be https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/ , watchdog will allow you to monitor a directory for changes and then run your program.  Depending on your needs, this might be better than cron or overkill.

Comment: I am on windows, I need the script to open in a new window, which is why I can't check for the file in the original script. If I have the script just waiting to run until it sees the file then a new window won't pop up for the user to notice right away, it would just keep running in another window that the user probably already covered with other windows from other applications... unless there is a way to force the window it is running in to come back to the top?